# Zend Dispatch - return variables from controller->action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a little issue with Zend. I am trying to make some fake HTTP requests and after the `module->controller->action` is executed, to return random variables that are set in that action. Like in the case of variables set with `view->assign(,)` - I can access them later from view file (.phtml).

Here is part of my code:

`/application/controller/IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init(){}
    public function indexAction()
    {
        #$this->view seems to be a NULL value from the fake request, so I can't pass variables to it 
        //$this->view->x = 'y';
        echo 'test';
        return array(
            'x' => 'y'
        );
    }
}
```

`/public/index2.php`

```
<?php
//--cut--
$application->bootstrap();
$options = array(
    'action' => 'index',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'module' => 'default'
);
if( isset($options['action'], $options['module'], $options['controller']) )
{

    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http ();
    $request->setModuleName($options['module'])->setActionName($options['action'])->setControllerName($options['controller']);  
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ()->returnResponse ( true );

    $response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http ();

    $frontController->getDispatcher ()->dispatch ( $request, $response );
    echo '$response:<b>Zend_Controller_Response_Http</b><br>';
    //This returns me the body of what I echo in the indexAction but not the variables.
    var_dump($response);
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign variables to view when the request is dispatched, you can create a Zend_View instance in the indexAction and assign values, as shown below:

```
  public function indexAction()
   {
     echo "test";
     $view = new Zend_View();
     $view->setBasePath(APPLICATION_PATH."/views/");
     $view->x = 'y';
     echo $view->render("index/index.phtml");
   }
```

Try embedding the variable in the index view script, and var_dump of your response will contain both the echoed "test" and the index.phtml output.

If you want to return the array to the response, use json:

```
      public function indexAction()
      {
         $array = array('x' => 'y');
         echo json_encode($array);
       }
```

index2.php:

```
        //.....
        var_dump($response);
        var_dump(json_decode($response->getBody()));
```

Comment: Your solution should work, but on many dispatches the json_encode and decode add significant time in the code execution compared to just return that array somehow. Just made some tests. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend Zend_Controller_Action for this because standard Action didn't receive returned variables.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to fetch the view parameters in the way you are trying (outside the view/MVC). This is because the action controller, in your case, `IndexController` only exists in memory for the duration of the dispatched method (`IndexAction`).

The parameters that are defined with the `view` class are only referenced when a call is made to `view->render()` and then just the HTML is generated.

You can however get the user defined variables (public scope) from **within the controller action** like so:

```
    class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            /** The view class uses PHP's magic set/get/isset methods to
            NULL any access to values that are protected (or more precisely 
            have a underscore _ prefix for the property name)

            hence $this->_view = null;
            **/

            /** we do however have access to this view (or create a new one if not already
            defined within the action controller) with: **/

            $view = $this->initView();

            /** An array of the public controller parameters **/
            $viewParams    = $view->getVars(); 

        }
    }
```

Also, the code dispatching theses requests can now be simplified:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setRequest(
    new Zend_Controller_Request_Http()->setParams($options)
)->dispatch();
```

*Note: I'm using version 1.11*

Comment: I am trying to access variables that I set in controller->action outside of the controller - in `index2.php`

Comment: @GamsterKatalin the action controller, where the instance of the view is created and/or assigned is set to null immediately after the dispatch of the `indexAction` method. Without an actual `.phtml` view file you cannot do what you want.