# Symfony Request: setController, setAction, setModule

Tags: php, symfony, request

In zf2 I have the option to make *fake* requests with a Zend/Request object. Thus I can do an internal Request. I want to execute a part of my site with a few data. Thus, I must use a Controller, Module and a Action.

How would I do that?

Here's a snippet of code from zf2 from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160256/zend-dispatch-return-variables-from-controller-action):

`/application/controller/IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init(){}
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //process some data from $_GET, $_POST, maybe (via framework, ofc).
    }
}
```

`/public/index2.php`

```
<?php
//--cut--
$application->bootstrap();
$options = array(
    'action' => 'index',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'module' => 'default'
);
if( isset($options['action'], $options['module'], $options['controller']) )
{
    //*
    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http ();
    $request->setModuleName($options['module'])->setActionName($options['action'])->setControllerName($options['controller']);
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ()->returnResponse ( true );
    //*/

    $response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http ();
    $frontController->getDispatcher ()->dispatch ( $request, $response );
    var_dump($response);
}
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: I don't think I follow your question, but maybe you mean this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers ?

Comment: e.g.: When you acces a link from any site via http request (browser) with a mvc pattern, you bootstrap the application, go into a ROUTE and execute the code in the controller/module/action for the ROUTE. I don't want to execute the code for that action with a http request, and by php code. With zf2 I can do that. In sf2, can't I?